TextSelectionThemeData selectionHandleColor not changing color in flutter
I am trying to change the selectionHandleColor in flutter using TextSelectionThemeData but it is not working. The cursorColor and selectionColor values are being respected but not the selectionHandleColor. Here is my code, not sure why only that field is not working
MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          colorSchemeSeed: MaterialSwatchGenerator.generate(Colors.blue),
          textSelectionTheme: const TextSelectionThemeData(
            cursorColor: Colors.red,
            selectionHandleColor: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        home: MainChild(),
      )



